Datetime strptime in python (hours are not showing)
I have date format:
train_time = [01/01/2021 00:00
01/01/2021 01:00
01/01/2021 02:00
01/01/2021 03:00
01/01/2021 04:00
01/01/2021 05:00
01/01/2021 06:00
01/01/2021 07:00
01/01/2021 08:00

I used this #train_time = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M").date() for date in train_time ]
the output train_time
[datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),

 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 1, 2),

 datetime.date(2021, 1, 2),

 datetime.date(2021, 1, 2),

The hours are not showing, how I can add the actual hour in the date format. any options that are availble to have proper format

You almost got it. If you remove date(), you will accomplish what you are looking for:
tt = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") for date in train_time ]

The reason you are not getting time part, because date() removes it. If you remove that, you will get the whole thing.
>>> tt[5]
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 5, 0)
>>> tt[5].date()
datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)
>>> tt[5].time()
datetime.time(5, 0)


That is amazing!! Thank you @Alp. I got this now [datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0),
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 1, 0),
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 2, 0),
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 3, 0),
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 4, 0),
datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 5, 0), can I remove the mintues as it sets to zeros

would you mind accepting the answer then ? :)
